# NET Core 5 : How to pass string list as a parameter?

Tags: rest, .net-core

My app is: NET Core 5 Web service.
I need to pass to HTTP PUT method a csv file.
The csv is like string1, string2, string3.

As one way I see: upload the csv file and then parse it to corresponding class.
But what else way? How to pass the string list in RESTful API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string list is longer than an URL should be, you define a body:

```
public class Model 
{
    public List<string> StringList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, you chose a HTTP method that accepts a body (PUT/POST most likely):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult YourMethod([FromBody] Model model)
{
    // and here, you can access model.StringList
}
```

Please note that an XLS or even CSV file is *not* just a string list. You would be better served by uploading the file and using an actual parser package that can handle that file format.

Comment: Thanx! It is exactly what I'd like to understand: what is better way.

Comment: Ok, how to call the method (as you wrote) in the client c# app?

Comment: The better way is to upload the file and read it with a specialized parser, instead of botching the whole process and destroying data by thinking the whole file parsing could just be done by pretending it's a stringlist in the frontend. It would also enable you to read more formats than just CSV.

Comment: How do you normally call methods? I don't know your app. How would you call a method with a simple int parameter for example?

Comment: I call it via HHTP PUT query etc. You says I can assign model as usually int or string parameter? I.e. in a client app:  1. public class Model  (the same as in Service) 2. Model model and pass it as an int?

Comment: Well, you somehow need this class in the client. That's why I asked. Normally, you connect client and server by some autogenerated code, so you don't have to manually do that. Like Swagger/Swashbuckle. They would create those classes for you.